# Css Table Formatting

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to replicate table formatting in HTML and CSS.

I don't need the search, pagination or show entries options, just the basic shaped layout that I can apply to a table.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've no idea where to start.

Sorry I forgot to add the link :( showing what I'd like to replicate.

http://datatables.net/styling/themes/smoothness

Comment: What is "this" you speak of?

Comment: `<table><tr><td>your table</td></tr></table>`
"this" table

Comment: Original Port updated to show link  http://datatables.net/styling/themes/smoothness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using css. Just add CSS to your table elements.

http://www.textfixer.com/resources/css-tables.php

Check this link